# Swagger Codegen is not working while generating java client for a Rest API having OAuth2.0 security

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, swagger

I am trying to generate a client using swagger codegen for a REST Api having OAuth 2.0 security. The call is following:

```
    E:\>java -jar swagger-codegen-distribution-2.1.2-M1.jar  -a access_token:df8eb092-e34f-48f9-b4ce-32cdd1ae2613 -i http://localhost:8080/someapi/api-docs -l java -o E:\projects\prototypes\ApiClient
```

But this call is not working and generating the following output as:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
reading from http://localhost:8080/someapi/api-docs
reading from http://localhost:8080/someapi/api-docs
usage: Codegen
-a,--auth                 addes authorization headers when fetching the
                       swagger definitions remotely. Pass in a
                       URL-encoded string of name:header with a comma
                       separating multiple values
-d,--debug-info           prints additional info for debugging
-h,--help                 shows this message
-i,--input-spec <arg>     location of the swagger spec, as URL or file
-l,--lang <arg>           client language to generate.
                       Available languages include:
                       [android, async-scala, java, jaxrs, nodejs,
                       objc, scalatra, scala, dynamic-html, html,
                       swagger, tizen, php, python]
-o,--output <arg>         where to write the generated files
-t,--template-dir <arg>   folder containing the template files
```

I have implemented recently the OAuth2.0 for this API so I assume that there is some problem with the authentication header I am setting with this APi as earlier the codegen was working well.

The following combinations I have tried for the -a option in the above command:

```
 -a access_token:<token>
 -a "access_token":<token>
 -a name:AUTHORIZATION,<token>
```

But nothing is working.
I am really in trouble with a demo today. Really appreciate any quick help

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you need OAuth2 authorization to access the Swagger definition or does your Swagger definition contain OAuth2 security for operations?

Comment: I think I need Oauth2 authorization to access the Swagger definition for the API

Comment: I don't think this is an authorization issue. For the output, try giving it a path under the current directory and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying the same thing myself and I will post what I think your issue is. Please try the command in the format given below.

```
java -jar <Path of codegen jar>/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i <path of swagger JSON>/swagger.json -l java -o <Output path>
```

In your command I do not see the JSON file name in "http://localhost:8080/someapi/api-docs"

If this does not work here is what I did to make the codegen work sucessfully.

**Installation**
To build from source, you need the following installed and available in your $PATH:

- Java 7 or 8
- Apache maven 3.3.3 or greater

The following commands can be used to build the codegen from the source

- git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
- cd swagger-codegen
- mvn clean package

You can also download the JAR (latest release) directly from maven.org

**Generating code**

You can generate the code for a particular JSON that you generated from the Swagger Editor using the following command.

- java -jar /swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i /swagger.json -l java -o

Additional details in relation to this can be found in the link https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#compatibility

The generated code has a maven build, so the library dependencies of the code is specified in the pom.xml.