# How to generate java code from the swagger 2.0 swagger-codegen-cli.jar

Tags: swagger

Does anyone know how to generate java code from swagger 2.0

My library is swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.2.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate java client code for swagger REST API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354557/how-to-generate-java-client-code-for-swagger-rest-api-documentation), [Swagger Codegen is not working while generating java client for a Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29537222/113116).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to generate either the server code or the client code.

1. Using https://generator.swagger.io, you can generate it online by providing your swagger.json
2. There are plugins for build tools like Maven and Gradle, for example [thebignet/swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/thebignet/swagger-codegen-gradle-plugin), they have examples on their github page
3. Using the command line by installing it on your OS (as explained on [the swagger codegen github page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)). They also show a `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar help` which should be of help!